# Deleting items in ListView using intent

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, android-intent

my problem is that im trying to delete items from ListView and for that I have a button in CustomAdapter.

Im setting this button an onClickListener and try to pass item name to main activity using Intent.

In Main when intent named "deleteProduct" is received the method deleteProduct is called and in this method im trying to pass to database a product name which to delete.

my CustomAdapter:

```
private DbItemDeleteListener deleteListener;

CustomAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Product> productNames,DbItemDeleteListener deleteListener) {
    super(context,R.layout.custom_list_row ,productNames);
    this.deleteListener = deleteListener;
}
 final Product singleProduct=getItem(position);
    final TextView productName=(TextView)customView.findViewById(R.id.ProductName);
    final Button CheckButton = (Button)customView.findViewById(R.id.CheckButton);
    final Button DeleteButton = (Button)customView.findViewById(R.id.DeleteButton);
 DeleteButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               String product=singleProduct.get_productname();
                deleteListener.delete(product);
            }
        });
```

MY Main:

```
DbItemDeleteListener deleteListener;
ArrayAdapter<Product> adapter;
ArrayList<Product> productnames=new ArrayList<>();
DBHandler dbhandler;
 @Override
public void delete(String productId){
    dbhandler.deleteProduct(productId);
}
```

And my DBHandler:

```
  public void deleteProduct(String productname){
    SQLiteDatabase db=getWritableDatabase();
    db.execSQL("DELETE FROM " +TABLE_PRODUCTS+ " WHERE "+ COLUMN_PRODUCTNAME+ "=\" "+ productname +"\";");
    }
```

Also im getting this message in logcat when i click delete button:

```
 Process: com.example.olev.shoppinglist, PID: 1836
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void com.example.olev.shoppinglist.DbItemDeleteListener.delete(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
            at com.example.olev.shoppinglist.CustomAdapter$3.onClick(CustomAdapter.java:80)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4756)
```

Comment: why dont you delete on listview button click directly ?

Comment: because button is created using CustomAdapter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't really need to use an intent just to delete a list item. Instead, use the observer pattern. First, create an interface:

```
public interface DbItemDeleteListener{
    public void delete(String productId);
}
```

Implement the interface in your Activity (your activity is probably not the greatest place to implement, but since it's where you're already doing the deleting, I'll stick with that):

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements DbItemDeleteListener{

    ...

    @Override
    public void delete(String productId){
        dbhandler.deleteProduct(productId);
    }
}
```

Then, pass an instance of your class that implements the listener to your adapter's constructor:

```
public CustomAdapter extends WhateverAdapter{
    private DbItemDeleteListener deleteListener;

    public MyAdapter(DbItemDeleteListener deleteListener){
        this.deleteListener = listener;
    }
}
```

Make sure you use this version of the constructor when you create your adapter.

Then, instead of the onClickListener sending an intent:

```
DeleteButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //get the product name and use the listener to delete

        ...

        deleteListener.delete(productId);
        notifyDataSetChanged();            
    }
}
```

But if you still plan on using intents for some reason:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onNewIntent(android.content.Intent)

> This is called for activities that set launchMode to "singleTop" in their package, or if a client used the FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP flag when calling startActivity(Intent).

What I'm guessing is happening is that instead of getting the current instance of your Main activity, you're actually creating a new instance. Therefore, you should be doing the same check in onCreate() instead.

So you can either set your activity's launch mode to something that will call onNewIntent:

```
<activity
    android:launchMode="singleTop"
    ...>
    ....
</activity>
```

and/or also add the flag to your intent:

```
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
```

Or, maybe easier, you can move the delete call to onCreate:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    ... //other onCreate() stuff

    if(getIntent() != null && getIntent().hasExtra("deleteProduct")){
        if (intent.getStringExtra("deleteProduct").equals("deleteProduct")) {
            deleteProduct();
        }
    }
}
```

Also, you should be checking for

```
intent.getStringExtra("deleteProduct").equals("deleteProduct")
```

not ".equals("deleteProcust") as in your sample code, but I assume that's a typo.

Comment: So is there an easier way to do this??

Comment: I updated my answer with a suggestion. Let me know if something's still not clear.

Comment: I think you might still be using the old constructor when you create your adapter ("myAdapter = new CustomAdapter(context, productNames)" instead of "myAdapter = new CustomAdapter(context, productNames, this)"), though I don't see any code where you do that. I see that I didn't mention that in my answer, so I'll add it.

Comment: Im creating my adapter instance on MainActivity@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ListView productList=(ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        dbhandler=new DBHandler(this,null,null,1);
        adapter= new CustomAdapter(this,productnames,this);
        getProductsFromDb();
        productList.setAdapter(adapter);


    }

Comment: this code doesnt produce error message but dont delete product either

Comment: @Ollikas is it possible that it's being deleted from your database but not from your adapter? Removing from the DB won't let your ListView know the item has been deleted. In addition to the code you've shown, to update your listview, you'll have to remove the item from your Adapter, and then call notifyDataSetChanged(). Sorry if you're already doing that, but I don't see it in the code you've posted so far.

Comment: no because if I restart my app ListView items are bieng loded from DB and  old items are still there. also i added getProductsFromDb() to my delete method and it doesnt work

Comment: here is my github repo to see all of the code : https://github.com/ollikas/ShoppingList

Comment: Perfect! 2 changes: in getProductsFromDb(), insert this as the first line: "productnames.clear();". Also, in deleteProduct() in your DB Handler, instead of execSql, you should be using delete like this: "public void deleteProduct(String productname){
        SQLiteDatabase db=getWritableDatabase();
        String[] args = {productname};
        db.delete(TABLE_PRODUCTS, COLUMN_PRODUCTNAME+"= ?", args);
        }"

Comment: @Ollikas I submitted a pull request to your repo with those changes.

Comment: THIS WORKS!!! Also is it possible to set a dialog to this delete button and when the dialog is confirmed, then delete the product. I have tried to search for a dialog solution, but all of them use showDialog(), which works if class where the button is extends Activity, but my CustomAdapter dont.

Comment: Sure. Just build the dialog in your activity's delete() method, and only call dbhandler.deleteProduct() and getProductsFromDB() after the user confirms.

Comment: I got it done, now I hve to do material design... But thank you again for your help. If I have more questions, I will let you know :D

Comment: my next problem is that I color my product barckground to green when the boolean is_checked is true. However if I reload the table for instance add a new product then all of the cheked items turn default color again. How to make them stay green?

Comment: @Ollikas you'll need to save the state of which items are checked any time you reload the data, then go back and re-set the check marks for any IDs that match after you re-load. You'll probably want to do that in onSaveInstanceState too, for when the screen rotates etc.

Comment: Cool. I thought you'd probably solved it already since I'd been away all weekend, but thought i'd answer in case you hadn't. Good luck!